# Trigger to delete the record from the table if it exists in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2019

I have the following table and table `employee_assignment_future`, which has the same columns.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employee_assignment (
    employee_id BIGINT,
    department_id BIGINT,
    job_title_id BIGINT,
    manager_id BIGINT,
    effective_start_date SMALLDATETIME,
    effective_end_date SMALLDATETIME,
    action_code VARCHAR(60)
);
```

I need a trigger that checks if a `employee_id` and `department_id` and `job_title_id` and `manager_id` exists in `employee_assignment_future` whenever the record from `employee_assignment` is UPDATED, and if so to delete it from `employee_assignment_future`. These 4 id's are foreign keys.

I came up with something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER t_v_employee_assignment_update3 on employee_assignment
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN           
    DECLARE @emp_id BIGINT = (SELECT employee_id from inserted)
    DECLARE @dep_id BIGINT = (SELECT department_id from inserted)
    DECLARE @job_id BIGINT = (SELECT job_title_id from inserted)
    DECLARE @man_id BIGINT = (SELECT manager_id from inserted)

    
    DELETE FROM employee_assignment_future
    WHERE @emp_id = employee_assignment_future.employee_id 
    AND @dep_id = employee_assignment_future.department_id
    AND @job_id = employee_assignment_future.job_title_id
    AND @man_id = employee_assignment_future.manager_id
END;

SELECT * FROM employee_assignment_future
SELECT * FROM employee_assignment

UPDATE employee_assignment
SET employee_id = 4, department_id = 2, job_title_id = 8, manager_id = 3, effective_start_date ='2019-11-13 00:00:00', effective_end_date = NULL, action_code = NULL
WHERE employee_id = 64;
```

However, it's not deleting anything from `employee_assignment_future`, and not updating anything in `employee_assignment`.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you, I tried something based on your advice, but It doesn't quite work, I updated the question, will highly appreciate your advice.

Comment: @DaleK Actually I changed to valid row ID in where clause, and it gives me such an error: 
`Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure t_v_employee_assignment_update, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 583]`
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` which I don't quite understand

Comment: I would venture to suggest you have a database normalization flaw here. One or more of those foreign key columns are actually dependent on another column, although it's hard to say exactly without knowing your situation. For example: perhaps `job_title` is part of `employee` information, or perhaps `department` is part of `job_title`. Equally you would expect `manager_id` to be part of `department`.

Comment: @Charlieface, it's a test database for learning purposes :) Thank you for your awareness

Comment: @Charlieface not sure the duplicate applies, that was an error that came later after OP tried stuff.  Question seems more about the correct use of inserted and maybe writing a joined delete.

Comment: @DaleK That is exactly what that question was about: questioner tried to do a single-row `select` and `update` on the `inserted` table in the trigger. If you have a better dupe please suggest, there are bound to be hundreds for this one, as this is [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: @Charlieface I think Dale K is right, the question was more about the correct use of inserted and maybe writing a joined delete. But your info is also very useful, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `DELETE` + `JOIN` should detect whether the record exists in the future and can then be deleted.

The following delete can be the entire body of your trigger.

```
    DELETE F
    FROM employee_assignment_future F
    INNER JOIN Inserted I
        ON I.employee_id = F.employee_id 
        AND I.department_id = F.department_id
        AND I.job_title_id = F.job_title_id
        AND I.manager_id = F.manager_id;
```

Note: You can't assume `Inserted` (or `Deleted`) have only a single row. You need to use set based operations and handle it having 0-N rows.

Comment: Tried this, have the same error: 
`Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure t_v_employee_assignment_update, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 583] Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

I think it is due to the fact that I have duplicates in the employee_assignment maybe..

Comment: Yes,, you're right it happens when I try to update the table to check the trigger.

`UPDATE employee_assignment 
SET employee_id = 4, department_id = 2, job_title_id = 8, manager_id = 3, effective_start_date ='2019-11-13 00:00:00', effective_end_date = NULL, action_code = NULL
WHERE employee_assignment.employee_id = 1;`

Maybe here because I have multiple id's 1? since there is no PK in the table.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I found another trigger and deleted it, and it's working. I made something similar, and was struggling with that error for a long time, and it was so simple, because of the other trigger. You saved me a lot of time, since I haven't had the idea about this error. Thank you again!